# Unit of measurement BlackBerry location.getSpeed

Tags: blackberry, gps, location

I am acquiring speed value in my BlackBerry App through;

```
double velocity   = location.getSpeed();
```

However, I am confused what is the unit of measurement for the returned speed. Is it kilometer per hour or meter per second? It is a double value. Does this mean it has no unit of measurement? Kindly explain.

Comment: [See javadoc for Location#getSpeed() here, which states unit are m/s](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/location/Location.html#getSpeed()).  Also, `getSpeed()` returns a float.  Best to use floats if that's all the precision you have anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output value velocity will be in **m/s**. 
To get the speed you will need to do this:

```
int speed = location.getSpeed();
```

which is in m/s, if you need to convert it to km/h use this:

```
int speed=(int) ((location.getSpeed()*3600)/1000);
```

if you need to convert it to mph use this:

```
int speed=(int) (location.getSpeed()*2.2369);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of Signare:

Generally whenever a unit is not defined / documented it should be one of the
*Base Units* or *Derived Units* of the [International System of Units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units)

Since speed is distance per time, the derived SI unit is [m/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_per_second).

If software would use unit km/h or miles for a public parameter called *speed* and
that without documentation, it would be a really bad piece of software.

Furthermore, to convert m/s to km/h, it's better to simply mutiply by `3.6` - that is much more readable than `3600/1000`, which is a cause of error, too (can result in an integer value)

```
double speedKmh = location.getSpeed() * 3.6;
```

To avoid confusing yourself, you better use the name `speedKmh` instead of speed, if it is not m/s.